# Error 550 when using CFFTP to remove a file

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-11, cfftp

I'm using `cfftp` to download files which I parse. I then need to delete the file from the server. I can list and download the files fine. However but I am butting my head against a problem that I can't seem to resolve.

Using the SAME PATH AND FILE NAME that allowed me to 'get' the file, I get an error when trying to remove it:

> Error: 550 file: No such file or directory

Again, the path and file name used both times are identical. I thought it might be a permission problem, but I can delete files using Filezilla (same credentials) with no problem.

Here is the call to remove:

```
<cfftp  action="remove"
        connection="myConnection1"
        passive="true"
        timeout="360"
        remotefile="#myPath##fileName#"
        item="file" >
```

Answer (score 2):

ANSWER (if not 'answer' - at least code that 'works')

```
<cfftp  action="remove"
        connection="myConnection1"
        item="#myPath##fileName#" >
```

This is not what the docs say- or how other examples on line convey it - but this worked for me